# JavaScript Help: Creating a Study Game - Matching & Fill in the Blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I'd like to create a simple JavaScript program to help me study but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to design it. I'm still rather new at JS, and this would actually be my first app not copied from a book.

Example scenario: I have countries and under each one I have events based in that country. England: Battle of Britain, King Arthur. US: Ford, First on the Moon. Etc.

I'm creating a game that would allow me to play multiple games with myself. One would be a simple matching game: You have a set of events and you have to match them to the country. Another would be asking a question and me filling in the blank.

My questions are these:

- In a program like this, using MongoDB, would I organize them into objects based on country then populate it with events, then put all the countries into a massive array?
- How would I randomize the answers? I know how to do random(), but I've never used it to randomize multiple potential answers. And how would I program it so that it's smart enough to randomize a country and then a property?
- And how do I randomize potential answers and a question? Would each question be its own object with the question and answer? Then how do I guarantee the answer is in my random list of potential answers?

Thanks for helping me work through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB stores all data in documents, so the less relationship between your data the better. Don't try to think or construct your data in a relational manner.

I would suggest to create a collection perhaps called `quiz`. and in `quiz` there are only 3 fields you need: `country`, `events` and `random`.

construct your data like this:

```
{
    country: COUNTRY,
    events: [ EVENT1, EVENT2, ... ],
    random: RANDOM
}
```

see this link for more information [The Random Attribute](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/random-attribute/)
Once you pick your "random" COUNTRY, you can randomize `events` from the array.
Then it is only a matter how to place your COUNTRY & EVENTS as Q&A.

P.S. Not clear about whether you want random COUNTRY and its random EVENTS, or you mean random COUNTRY with irrelevant random EVENTS.

Comment: Wow, excellent! Thank you!! I meant a random country then events some of which are wrong. E.g. the random country is England and the random events (answers) are Jack the Ripper's murders, Princess Diana's wedding, and Watergate scandal. So you'd pick Watergate as the one that doesn't belong.

Comment: I'm glad it helps.
So in your case of random events as the WRONG answer, you need to take 3 CORRECT events from that same array, and then pick a randomize COUNTRY (not identical) and pick one of its EVENT (it would be the WRONG one).

re document type NoSQL, you may read more articles and try to learn its structure. Even experienced programmers sometimes make this structural mistake and run into problem in later stage when scaling is needed.
Good luck!